# Is there a preConstruction alike for a spring stereotype annotation?

Tags: java, spring

I could make use of preConstruction=true for my domain class so that i can make use of autowired fields in the constructor such as this :

```
@Configurable(preConstruction=true)
public class MyDomain {

  @Autowired private MyContext context;

  public MyDomain() {
    context.doSomething(this); // access the autowired context in the constructor
  }

}
```

But then, what is the equivalence for preConstruction when i would like to access autowired fields in a class with the normal stereotype annotation such as @Repository or @Service  aside from constructor injection (Currently using spring 3.x here ..) ?

```
@Repository
public class MyDomainRepository {

  @Autowired private MyContext context;

  public MyDomain() {
    // cannot access the autowired context in the constructor
    context.doSomething(this); 
  }

}
```

Comment: have you tried to use both annotations in `MyDomainRepository`?

Comment: Hello. I dont think that'd be appropriate since @Configurable is for non managed beans which is instantiated using the normal java way, like the new operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think something like this is available for regular Spring beans, but the usual way to solve this problem is to use `@PostConstruct`-annotated method instead of constructor:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    context.doSomething(this);    
}
```

This method will be called by Spring after all dependencies are injected.

Comment: or build your classes through a factory which has environment access. i dont think you can get injection before construction - there has to be in instance to inhect into. you could do something like public MyClass() {super(someMethod())}, and gain context access in that method, but that wouldf be VERY ugly